# Rsync hangs. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, router, rsync

I try to rsync somefile from my Ubuntu to the Xiaomi mini router having padavan firmware

```
rsync -vvv --rsync-path="/opt/bin/rsync" ~/somefile root@router:/etc/storage/dnsmasq/
```

But it hangs, giving me the following:

```
opening connection using: ssh -l root router /opt/bin/rsync --server -vvve.Ls . /etc/storage/dnsmasq/  (9 args)
[sender] make_file(somefile,*,0)
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=633
recv_file_name(somefile)
received 1 names
recv_file_list done
get_local_name count=1 /etc/storage/dnsmasq/
```

local: rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31

remote:  rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31

Comment: Logging in over ssh works ok? Have you tried `scp` instead of `rsync` as well? Eg. `scp ~/somefile root@router:/etc/storage/dnsmasq/`

Comment: scp works perfectly. There is the problem with rsync only